# 404 error on calling bucket file get metadata Google Storage

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

The error message

> {"code":404,"errors":[],"response":{"headers":{"access-control-expose-headers":"content-type,x-firebase-storage-version,x-goog-upload-url,x-goog-upload-status,x-goog-upload-command,x-gupload-uploadid,x-goog-upload-header-content-length,x-goog-upload-header-content-type,x-goog-upload-protocol,x-goog-upload-status,x-goog-upload-chunk-granularity,x-goog-upload-control-url","connection":"keep-alive","content-length":"9","content-type":"text/plain; charset=utf-8","date":"Fri, 18 Feb 2022 07:10:30 GMT","etag":"W/"9-0gXL1ngzMqISxa6S1zx3F4wtLyg"","keep-alive":"timeout=5","vary":"Origin","x-powered-by":"Express"}},"message":"Not Found"}

Using firebase emulator and calling `getMetadata()` through firebase functions

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import admin = require("firebase-admin");
var cred = require("../xxx.json");
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(cred),
  storageBucket: "xxx.appspot.com",
});
const bucket = admin.storage().bucket();

export const metadata = functions.https.onRequest(
  async (request, response) => {
    await bucket
      .file("xxx/xxx.png")
      .getMetadata()
      .then((v) => response.send(v))
      .catch((e) => response.send(e));
  }
);
```

I get the error message after opening the generated link by firebase emulator:

```
http://localhost:5001/xxx-xxx/us-central1/metadata
```

What could be the problem here?

Comment: Hi, Can you please tell us the Node JS version, Firebase version that you are using. And the code is in typescript right?

Comment: @ZeenathSN node 14, firebase 10.0.0,

Comment: Have you tried with command `npm run serve` at the functions folder?